# How to handle an invalid CORS preflight request?

Tags: cors, preflight

Suppose a CORS preflight request comes in, but it specifies an unsupported value for one or more `Access-Control-Request-*` headers.  How should the server communicate this back to the browser?

Some examples:

- The browser sends a preflight request with `Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT`, but the server doesn't allow PUT requests for the specified resource.
- The browser sends a preflight request with `Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-PINGOTHER`, but the server doesn't allow/understand that header.

The only clue I could find was located in the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests), which indicates that the server should "terminate this request" if there is a problem with the preflighted response, but I'm not sure what that looks like in practice (is the server really supposed to terminate the connection without sending back a response??).

Or, does the server not need to bother with validation at all, since the browser will know it did something wrong just by checking the `Access-Control-Allow-*` response headers?

Answer (score 1):

[Tomcat's CORS Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) returns a 403 response when an invalid CORS preflight request is received:

> If request is invalid, or is not permitted, then request is rejected with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden). A [flowchart](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png) that demonstrates request processing by this filter is available.

Granted, the documentation doesn't explain **why** it does this, but at least it serves as a starting point.